# How to get specific values from a list of values in a dictionary and store in unique lists?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary which looks something like this:

```
dicts = 
{"A" : ['shape_one.csv','shape_two.csv','volume_one.csv','volume_two.csv'],
"B" : ['shape_one.csv','shape_two.csv','volume_one.csv','volume_two.csv']}
```

All the values inside the list of values are paths of a .csv file which I extracted using os.walk().
Now I want to just extract the values which have the string "volume_" in them, and store these values in a list. I want to do this for each key in the dictionary.

I am using python 3.8. I would appreciate any help, as I am a non-programmer just trying to finish a task programmatically. thank you in advance.

The output should return seperate lists for  each key, even if the values share the same name.

```
volume_list_A = ['volume_one.csv','volume_two.csv']

volume_list_B = ['volume_one.csv','volume_two.csv']
```

I have tried doing:
`volume_list = [x for x in list(dicts.values()) if "volume_" in x]`

but this just returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension in a dictionary comprehension:

```
dicts = {"A" : ['shape_one','shape_two','volume_one','volume_two'],
         "B" : ['shape_one','shape_two','volume_one','volume_two']}

out = {f'volume_list_{k}': [x for x in l if x.startswith('volume_')]
       for k,l in dicts.items()}
```

*NB. if you want `volume_` anywhere in the string (not only in the beginning) use `if 'volume_' in x` in place of `if x.startswith('volume_')`.*

Output:

```
{'volume_list_A': ['volume_one', 'volume_two'],
 'volume_list_B': ['volume_one', 'volume_two']}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Can you please see the edit I have made and see if this response still works ?

Comment: @VasudeV yes, this should still work

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem for now. I want to know though, how do I get independent lists instead of dictionary of lists ?

Comment: You should not try to generate variable names dynamically, [this is a very bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables). Instead access the lists using `out['volume_list_A']`. Or keep the original key: `out = {k: [x for x in l if x.startswith('volume_')] for k,l in dicts.items()}` then `out['A']`.